# 'localtime' function crashes on second call

Tags: c, localtime

So, I wrote the next function:

```
void actualizetime(){
  puts("actualizetime called"); //debugging purposes.
  time_t rawtime;
  puts("static time_t defined"); //debugging purposes.
  struct tm *timeinfo;
  puts("struct tm * defined"); //debugging purposes.
  time(&rawtime);
  puts("time function called"); //debugging purposes.
  timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
  puts("timeinfo has localtime"); //debugging purposes.

  actualtime.year = timeinfo->tm_year + 1900;
  actualtime.month = timeinfo->tm_mon;
  actualtime.day = timeinfo->tm_mday;
  actualtime.hour = timeinfo->tm_hour;
  actualtime.min = timeinfo->tm_min;
  actualtime.sec = timeinfo->tm_sec;
}
```

The thing is, this function works great only once. The second time the function is called, `timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);` crashes. What's going wrong? and, how can I fix it?

I don't think the `actualtime` struct is important but, anyhow:

```
struct {
  int year;
  int month;
  int day;

  int hour;
  int min;
  int sec;
} actualtime;
```

***EDIT***:

The complete program (linux only):

**WARNING**: To run this program you have to be root, and have on root file system a dir called `/pragma/regfiles/`

```
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

void actualizetime(void);
void openregfile(void);
void closeregfile(void);
void addreg(char *,char *);
void terminate(void);

char *months[] = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};

FILE *regfile;

struct {
  int year;
  int month;
  int day;

  int hour;
  int min;
  int sec;
} actualtime;

void actualizetime(){
  puts("-actualizetime called"); //debugging purposes.
  time_t rawtime;
  puts("-static time_t defined"); //debugging purposes.
  struct tm *timeinfo;
  puts("-struct tm * defined"); //debugging purposes.
  time(&rawtime);
  puts("-time function called"); //debugging purposes.
  timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
  puts("-timeinfo has localtime"); //debugging purposes.

  actualtime.year = timeinfo->tm_year + 1900;
  actualtime.month = timeinfo->tm_mon;
  actualtime.day = timeinfo->tm_mday;
  actualtime.hour = timeinfo->tm_hour;
  actualtime.min = timeinfo->tm_min;
  actualtime.sec = timeinfo->tm_sec;
}

void openregfile(void){
  char route[64];
  struct stat *st;

  if(!route){
    puts("Error initializing files");
    exit(1);
  }

  actualizetime();

  sprintf(route, "/pragma/regfiles/%04d/", actualtime.year);
  if(stat(route, st) < 0){
    if(mkdir(route, 0600) < 0){
      puts("ERROR: cannot create directory for regs files! (1)");
      exit(1);
    }
  }

  sprintf(route, "/pragma/regfiles/%04d/%s", actualtime.year, months[actualtime.month]);
  if(stat(route, st) < 0){
    if(mkdir(route, 0600) < 0){
      puts("ERROR: cannot create directory for regs files! (2)");
      exit(1);
    }
  }

  sprintf(route, "/pragma/regfiles/%04d/%s/%02d.reg", actualtime.year, months[actualtime.month], actualtime.day);
  if((regfile = fopen(route, "a")) == NULL){
    puts("ERROR: cannot create reg file!");
    exit(1);
  }
  addreg("log", "reg start");
}

void closeregfile(){
  addreg("log", "reg stop");
  fclose(regfile);
}

void addreg(char *label,char *msg){
  puts("-before actualize time");  //debugging purposes.
  actualizetime();
  puts("-after actualize time");  //debugging purposes.
  printf("%d%d%d", actualtime.hour, actualtime.min, actualtime.sec);
  fprintf(regfile, "[%s]:%04d%s%02d_%02d%02d%02d %s\n", label, actualtime.year, months[actualtime.month], actualtime.day, actualtime.hour, actualtime.min, actualtime.sec, msg);
  fflush(regfile);
}






int main(void){
  openregfile();

  //Do something

  terminate();
  return 0;
}

void terminate(void){
  closeregfile();
  puts("Terminating...");
}
```

Comment: Please show a minimally, complete program.  I don't see any memory/pointer issue, so something else is going on that cannot be determined from this code snippet.

Comment: localtime I believe has been depreciated. I believe locatime_s is favored.

Comment: @ydobonebi: `localtime` has not been deprecated by the C standard. Microsoft might *say* it's deprecated, but Microsoft doesn't control C (and doesn't even implement the current standard, or the one before that).

Comment: @KeithThompson I suppose another reason I really should stop trusting microsoft :)

Comment: @ydobonebi: C11 does add a `localtime_s` function. It's specified in Annex K, which is optional; an implementation can predefine `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` to indicate that it conforms to it.

Comment: are you working with multi thread application

Comment: No. Is a program that just does a lot of log into a file.
I'm working on a small program...

Comment: Note that `st_mon` encodes January as month 0 and December as month 11.

Comment: I ran the code in a loop, called from main() for 10 iterations.   It did not fail.  The source of the problem is not in the posted code

Comment: 1) How do you know code crashes at `timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);`?  2) What `#include files` were used? 3) Show minimally compete code

Comment: Given that the code shown is 'safe' and you are not working with a multi-threaded program, you must have some other memory abuse going on, probably in an area mostly or completely unrelated to this code.  You should take a look at running your code under [`valgrind`](http://www.valgrind.org/) if possible — or use some other memory monitor — to see whether that is the trouble.

Comment: @chux It's a little wired... when the program is ludicrously small it works fine, but as it grows, it crashes in the same part. I mean, the debuging message 'time function called' is the last thing shown.

Comment: Can you really not reproduce the problem without having to write to a local directory `/pragma/regfiles/` as root??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This causes undefined behaviour:

```
struct stat *st;
if(stat(route, st) < 0){
```

You are passing an uninitialized variable `st` to a library function, which causes undefined behaviour.

Reading the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) for `stat` would tell you that you are supposed to supply a pointer to a buffer that already exists, and the `stat` function will fill in.

For example:

```
struct stat st = { 0 };     // good practice to zero-initialize
if ( stat(route, &st) < 0 ) {
```

Answer (score 2):

the posted (edited) code does not cleanly compile

Suggest always compiling with all warnings enabled.

Then you would have see the following two messages:

```
...c:49:6 warning: the addres of 'route' will always be evaluated as 'true' [-Waddress]

if(!route){

...c:57:10: warning 'st' is used unitialized in this function [-Wuninitalized]

if(stat(route, st) < 0){
```

strongly suggest fixing the compile problems before event thinking about trying to run the program.

Comment: Thank you, I'll do.
How do you get all that warnings?
I run gcc with 'pedantic' flag and I can't see what you posted.

Comment: as a minimum: 'gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -c'   The '-c' is so the call is for the compile step rather than the link step.

Comment: in the function: openregfile(), the stack array 'char route[64]' is used without being initialized in the line: 'if(!route){'  strongly suggest removing that whole 'if' code block

Comment: when creating directories, for instance with mkdir, need the permissions to include the execute permission and for later accessing both the read and write permissions.

Comment: 1) the list of #include files seems to be missing <sys/types.h> and perhaps <unistd.h> 2) when calling stat(), the second parameter is the address of an instance of the   'struct stat', not a simple pointer   so: struct stat st;  ... if( stat(route, &st) < 0)    Strongly suggest reading the man page (and googling examples of usage) for each system function being called

Comment: the right way to display an error after a call to a system function is not using puts() nor printf().  rather use perror().    Perror will output the text you insert and output the appropriate (given the errno value) system error message

Comment: Thank you @user3629249, you helped me more than anyone.